# Error while using msbuild command for sln file

Tags: windows, msbuild

I am trying to build a sln file by using following command

```
/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe "MvcApplication1/MvcApplication1.sln" /t:MvcApplication
```

It id throwing me following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.2053.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: t:MvcApplication

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

But when i am trying to use the same command without any argument it is building successfully on my default target.
I  don't know where it publishing my web and why it is not taking any of the argument.

Comment: `/t` asks for a valid task name, while `MvcApplication` is not likely to be the one. Carefully learn MSBuild please.

Comment: in that case it should throw project not found error  which i am getting when i am executing same from power shell

Comment: What exactly is the "project not found error"?

Comment: @LexLi Please read the error again and the comment. I am not getting ```project not found error```..i am getting ```MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified``` and btw i am able to run same command from power shell

Comment: What is the folder structure? From your text, no one can tell if "MvcApplication1/MvcApplication1.sln" is a valid relative path or not. Try to use absolute path first to make sure you use the correct path, and then calculate the relative path from there. BTW, MSBuild in .NET installation folder is the legacy version. New versions are part of Visual Studio.